# paypal IPN works with Destop web-browsers but not mobile web-browsers

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Hi I have an issue where I have a PayPal form on my website when I click to pay using a Desktop web-browser, the transaction completes with all IPN Posted data from PayPal being correct! However when I use an android or IOS device the transaction completes, but there is no Posted data from PayPal when user clicks the return to business-name site? Now if I do another transaction with the Desktop web-browser using an android user-agent, I get the same results that is happening with the mobile devices (No IPN posted data from PayPal)? My form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="hug33472-facilitator@hugtech.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Power-Ball Roller Android App">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="PBRAND0114">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.37">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://hugtech.com/cgi-bin/pbandroid/secret">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://hugtech.com/power_ball/mob">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"  border="0" name="submit"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Thanks, Larry

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're confusing PDT and IPN.  They're very similar except that PDT is meant to send data back to your return URL while IPN is meant to send data to an entirely separate script that isn't part of your checkout flow.  IPN is the recommended method of updating your database, sending out emails, etc.  Based on what you're saying about clicking the return link, though,  you must be using PDT.

I haven't specifically tested PDT with mobile checkouts, but I know IPN does trigger regardless of the payment method or device.  So make sure you're using IPN, not PDT, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Andrew, I am not confusing PDT and IPN as we use a perl IPN listener script for the backend and that is where PayPal posts to. Remember where I said it works for Desktop Web-browsers and not Mobile Web-Browsers?

Comment: You said "but there is no Posted data from PayPal when user clicks the return to business-name site."  IPN has nothing to do with the user clicking to return to the site.  That would be PDT.

Comment: I also don't see the notify_url parameter in your code, so if you are using you must have configured it in your PayPal profile instead..??  If you're certain you're using IPN and you do have it enabled in your profile then you must have a problem in your IPN script code keeping it from running with particular txn_types or something like that.  You can check IPN History in your PayPal account as well as your web server logs to see what's going on there.